# Drupal 8 - How to block search engines from reading or indexing a specific content type(Resource)

Tags: search-engine, drupal-8

I don't want to see resource content type nodes in the google search result.

I know, I can add the URL in the robots.txt if I have to restrict any particular content.

But, how can I restrict all the nodes of one particular content type in Drupal 8 from being crawled by the search engines like google?

Comment: Are you asking about the internal Drupal search module or external engines, or both?

Comment: External search engines (google result)

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to install the [metatag module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag), you will need to add the field metatag to the content type that you're trying to exclude from google. To exclude from google make sure you checked in the metatag dropdown while editing the pages the following:

```
Prevents search engines from indexing this page.
```

If you have too many, you would need to write a hook_update in order to get the changes applied to all the existing pages.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of to block search engines is through `robots.txt`.

With Drupal, in order to block an entire type of content, you must make sure there are no ad-hoc aliases. Check `/admin/config/search/path`. Any abnormal aliases to instances of your content will allow the search engines to bypass general rules that you set.

Then, add a rule to `robots.txt` to disallow the pattern for that content.

Example:

```
Disallow: /node/
```

If you have some specific subset of content that you would like to block consider using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to create path patterns that will allow you to easily target those subsets with `robots.txt` rules.